lualatexja behaves strangely with font changes under beamer environment
\documentclass[aspectratio=196,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmainjfont{Meiryo}

\title{brabrabra}
\date{\today}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{test}
  The Quick 

\end{document}


The lualatexja-fontspec
should output The Quick in Calibri, but for some reason
, it outputs The Quick in a different font.
On the other hand, Mayrio is output correctly.

Beamer uses sans serif text by default. Instead of changing the main font, change the sans font (or use the serif font theme):
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec} 
\setsansfont{Zapfino}
\setmainjfont{Meiryo}

\title{brabrabra}
\date{\today}
\author{author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  The Quick 
\end{frame}

\end{document}


